# What happens behind the scenes when a value is set to null?

Tags: c#, null, assignment-operator

Lets say I have a populated array of objects.

```
 Resource[] list = new Resource[100000];
```

And once in a while, I would like to change an object in this list to a default value.

```
 Resource defaultResource = new Resource();
```

And later on, I would like to check if the item is default or not.
So, I am wondering what the performance differences might be in setting the list object to a default value, versus setting a value to null.

```
 list[i] = defaultResource; /*versus*/ list[i] = null;
```

So really, I would like to know what goes on behind the scenes when a value is set to null versus setting it equal to something else.

Sorry if this is a dumb question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's not much difference between setting a variable to an existing object vs. setting it to `null`. In both cases, the object that has been referenced by that variable before would get one step closer to becoming eligible for garbage collection, regardless of the new value stored in that variable being a `null` or a different object. The rest of the assignment goes in the same way, too: CLR does not maintain reference count, so nothing special needs to happen specifically at the point when the assignment is made.

It may be beneficial to store a default object in place of a `null` to avoid extensive `null` checking at runtime, though: doing so simplifies the code, and reduces the need for branching at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

One possible option to consider for your scenario - you want the simplification of not having to write null checking code.

Consider subclassing your `Resource` class with a stub that represents a default value.

```
public class NoResource : Resource { }

// ... later

if (res is NoResource) { 
  // handle default value
}
```

This way, your code is still able to work with `Resource` objects as it expects to be able to, and you can optionally check for a default `Resource` easily.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it doesn't quite fit my case though.